# bigbluebutton 0.9 drops meeting with people through voicebridge after last web user quit

Tags: freeswitch, bigbluebutton

We have Bigbluebutton v0.9 server and meetings with people on phone through voicebridge (freeswitch out of the box with BBB). The problem is: if any user enter to such conference by web client - the conference will be finished and drops all callers after the last web user exit. Any idea how to tell BBB count users on voicebridge as normal participants and keep conference alive?

Answer (score 0):

I've posted same question in BBB google group and one of the developers answered that this behavior is "by design".
Maybe later someone will add something more, so the topic is here: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bigbluebutton-users/XVfb5ECgX7Y)